# How to easily convert my LinearLayouts into RelativeLayouts

Tags: android, xml, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I have 4 `LinearLayout`s that I would like to convert into `RelativeLayout`s.  Using my `xml` here, I have, as my preferred format:

- ImageButton
- ImageButton
- TextView
- Button

How do I change to `RelativeLayout` to always display the 1st `ImageButton` on the very top, always display the `Button` at the very bottom, and have the 2nd `ImageButton` below the first `ImageButton`, with the `TextView` between the 2nd `ImageButton` and the regular `Button`?

Thanks!

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:gravity="center">

    <ImageView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/image_view" />

    <TextView 
        android:text="@+id/TextView01"  
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/message" />

    <Button
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:textStyle="bold" 
        android:id="@+id/action_button"    
        android:selectAllOnFocus="false" 
        android:layout_height="100dip" 
        android:text="Click here to Crop"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I just want to know the correct term to align something above with something below - so I set the top button to hug the parent top, and I want the button below to be right below that with a bit of padding...etc

Comment: Have you googled? http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout-objects.html#relativelayout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ImageButton android:layout_below="@+id/Button01" 
            android:id="@+id/ImageButton01"     
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent">
</ImageButton>
<ImageButton android:layout_below="@+id/ImageButton01" 
            android:id="@+id/ImageButton02" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent">
</ImageButton>
<TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
             android:id="@+id/TextView01" 
             android:text="@+id/TextView01" 
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"      
             android:layout_below="@+id/ImageButton02">
</TextView>
<Button android:text="@+id/Button01" 
             android:id="@+id/Button01" 
             android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
             android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"   
             android:layout_width="fill_parent">
 </Button>
</RelativeLayout>
```

also you may want to look [here](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-relativelayout/) and [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-relativelayout.html)

Answer (score 1):

RelativeLayouts are very easy to build if you use an IDE that helps you with the layout parameter options.

What you need are for example android:layout_alignParentTop="true" and android:layout_below="@id/xxxxxxxx"

This link will get you started:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout-objects.html